# error is: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

```
var vb:Float
vb = 12.13
print(vb)
```

Generates the following error:

> error: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL

Comment: Did you tried `var vb:Float = 12.13` ?

Comment: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL error

Answer (score 3):

This is a weird problem, i know
This happen when the playground set to manually run
In order to avoid this problem you have to set the playground from manually run to
automatically run.

- Press and hold the little triangle from top of the console and the options will pop up
- Step 2: Now choose automatically run from there

Thats it!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

#### Playground:

> error: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL

This indicates that a variable declared directly in the playground has not been initialized at the same time of it's declaration.

Variables declared like this at the top level are to be initialized either during declaration or atleast in `init`, but since playground doesn't have `init`, it needs to be initialized upfront.

So:

```
var vb: Float //error: variables currently must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL
vb = 12.13
print(vb)
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Playground {        
    var vb: Float

    init() {} //Error: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

    func main() {
        vb = 12.13
        print(vb)
    }        
}
```

---

Top-level objects are those which are directly written in the playground, i.e. aren't inside a function/class/struct and so they're treated like explicitly initialized properties.

Thus, `var vb: Float` indicates to the compiler that it's a variable named `vb` of type `Float` which should have an explicit value assigned to it.
But when it finds out that there is no assignment operation, it throws a compile-time error.

---

### Solutions:

1. Explicit assignment

   ```
   var vb: Float = 12.13 //initializes with an explicit value
   print(vb)
   ```
2. Declare as `Implicitly Unwrapped Optional` with `!`

   ```
   var vb: Float! //initializes as nil
   vb = 12.13
   print(vb)
   ```
3. Declare as `Optional` with `?`

   ```
   var vb: Float? //initializes as nil
   vb = 12.13
   print(vb)
   ```
4. Wrap it in a function:

   ```
   func doSomething() {
       var vb: Float
       vb = 12.13
       print(vb)
   }

   doSomething()
   ```

---

***NOTE: This answer is specific to top-level objects in Read-Eval-Print-Loop (REPL)***